Fetching external sources
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 15 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
Preparing
Analyzing dependencies 

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-RunnerTests`: (``)

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
-> Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`
cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '10.25.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `connectivity_plus` from `.symlinks/plugins/connectivity_plus/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '10.25.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '10.25.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `shared_preferences_foundation` from `.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences_foundation/darwin`

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
  CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_3_5.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/10.25.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/10.25.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_d_d_6.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/d/d/6/ReachabilitySwift/5.2.2/ReachabilitySwift.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/10.25.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/10.25.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_4_2_c.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/4/2/c/FlutterMacOS/3.16.0/FlutterMacOS.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_9_f.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/9/f/FirebaseFirestore/10.25.0/FirebaseFirestore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_6_3_6.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/6/3/6/FirebaseAuth/10.25.0/FirebaseAuth.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_8_b_d.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/10.25.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/9/f/FirebaseFirestore/10.25.0/FirebaseFirestore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_4_7_f.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/4/7/f/FirebaseCoreExtension/10.25.0/FirebaseCoreExtension.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_3_1_8.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/1/8/FirebaseFirestoreInternal/10.25.0/FirebaseFirestoreInternal.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_b_c_7.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/b/c/7/FirebaseSharedSwift/10.25.0/FirebaseSharedSwift.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/10.25.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_8_4.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/7.13.3/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/7.12.0/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/7.13.0/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/7.13.2/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/7.13.3/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/7.12.0/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/7.13.0/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/7.13.2/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/7.13.3/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_7_9_1.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/7/9/1/FirebaseCoreInternal/10.25.0/FirebaseCoreInternal.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/10.25.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/10.24.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/10.23.1/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/10.23.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/10.22.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/10.21.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/10.20.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/10.19.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/10.18.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/10.17.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/10.16.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/10.15.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/10.14.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/10.13.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/10.12.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/10.11.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/10.10.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/10.9.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/10.8.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/10.7.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/1.20240116.2/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/1.20240116.2/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/1.20240116.2/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/1.20240116.2/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/1.20240116.2/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/1.20240116.2/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/1.20240116.2/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/1.20240116.2/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/1.20240116.2/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/1.20240116.2/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/1.20240116.2/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/1.20240116.2/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/1.20240116.2/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/1.20240116.2/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/1.20240116.2/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/1.20240116.2/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/1.20240116.2/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/1.20240116.2/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/1.20240116.2/abseil.podspec.json exists! 
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/c/8/7/gRPC-C++/1.62.0/gRPC-C++.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/4/2/c/FlutterMacOS/3.13.2/FlutterMacOS.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/4/2/c/FlutterMacOS/3.13.0/FlutterMacOS.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/4/2/c/FlutterMacOS/3.0.0/FlutterMacOS.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update

――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

### Command

```
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.0/bin/pod install --verbose
```

### Report

* What did you do?

* What did you expect to happen?

* What happened instead?


### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.15.2
        Ruby : ruby 3.3.0 (2023-12-25 revision 5124f9ac75) [x86_64-darwin23]
    RubyGems : 3.5.3
        Host : macOS 14.4.1 (23E224)
       Xcode : 15.3 (15E204a)
         Git : git version 2.39.3 (Apple Git-146)
Ruby lib dir : /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.0/lib
Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
```

### Plugins

```
cocoapods-clean       : 0.0.1
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.5
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.1
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.6.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0
```

### Podfile

```ruby
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '12.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)


flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!  # required by simple_permission

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.1'  # required by simple_permission
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```

### Error

```
JSON::ParserError - Failed to parse JSON at file: '/Users/macbookpro/.cocoapods/repos/trunk/Specs/4/2/c/FlutterMacOS/3.0.0/FlutterMacOS.podspec.json'.

unexpected token at '{
  "name": "FlutterMacOS",
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "summary": "A UI toolkit for beautiful and fast apps.",
  "description": "Flutter is Google's UI toolkit for building beautiful, fast apps for mobile, web, desktop, and embedded devices from a single codebase.\nThis pod vends the macOS release mode Flutter engine framework. It is compatible with application frameworks created with this version of the engine and tools.",
  "homepage": "https://flutter.dev/",
  "license": {
    "type": "BSD",
    "text": "Copyright 2014 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.\n\nRedistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification,\nare permitted provided that the following conditions are met:\n\n    * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright\n      notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.\n    * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above\n      copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following\n      disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials provided\n      with the distribution.\n    * Neither the name of Google Inc. nor the names of its\n      contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived\n      from this software without specific prior written permission.\n\nTHIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS \"AS IS\" AND\nANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED\nWARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE\nDISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR\nANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES\n(INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES;\nLOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON\nANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT\n(INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS\nSOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.\n"
  },
  "authors": {
    "Flutter Dev Team": "flutter-dev@googlegroups.com"
  },
  "source": {
    "http": "https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra_release/flutter/d1b9a6938ad77326ac3a94d92bbc77933ed829ed/darwin-x64-release/FlutterMacOS.framework.zip"
  },
  "documentation_url": "https://flutter.dev/docs",
  "pl'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/json.rb:66:in `rescue in from_json'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/json.rb:61:in `from_json'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:759:in `from_string'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:733:in `from_file'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:188:in `specification'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver/lazy_specification.rb:37:in `specification'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/delegate.rb:348:in `block in delegating_block'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/delegate.rb:349:in `block in delegating_block'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:178:in `dependencies_for'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:18:in `block in dependencies_for'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:77:in `with_no_such_dependency_error_handling'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:17:in `dependencies_for'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:809:in `block in group_possibilities'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:808:in `reverse_each'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:808:in `group_possibilities'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:779:in `possibilities_for_requirement'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:761:in `push_state_for_requirements'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:744:in `require_nested_dependencies_for'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:727:in `activate_new_spec'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:684:in `attempt_to_activate'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in `process_topmost_state'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1082:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1080:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:125:in `analyze'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:422:in `analyze'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:244:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:162:in `install!'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.0/bin/pod:25:in `load'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.0/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
```

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=Failed+to+parse+JSON+at+file%3A+%27%2FUsers%2Fmacbookpro%2F.cocoapods%2Frepos%2Ftrunk%2FSpecs%2F4%2F2%2Fc%2FFlutterMacOS%2F3.0.0%2FFlutterMacOS.podspec.json%27.%0A%0Aunexpected+token+at+%27%7B%0A++%22name%22%3A+%22FlutterMacOS%22%2C%0A++%22version%22%3A+%223.0.0%22%2C%0A++%22summary%22%3A+%22A+UI+toolkit+for+beautiful+and+fast+apps.%22%2C%0A++%22description%22%3A+%22Flutter+is+Google%27s+UI+toolkit+for+building+beautiful%2C+fast+apps+for+mobile%2C+web%2C+desktop%2C+and+embedded+devices+from+a+single+codebase.%5CnThis+pod+vends+the+macOS+release+mode+Flutter+engine+framework.+It+is+compatible+with+application+frameworks+created+with+this+version+of+the+engine+and+tools.%22%2C%0A++%22homepage%22%3A+%22https%3A%2F%2Fflutter.dev%2F%22%2C%0A++%22license%22%3A+%7B%0A++++%22type%22%3A+%22BSD%22%2C%0A++++%22text%22%3A+%22Copyright+2014+The+Chromium+Authors.+All+rights+reserved.%5Cn%5CnRedistribution+and+use+in+source+and+binary+forms%2C+with+or+without+modification%2C%5Cnare+permitted+provided+that+the+following+conditions+are+met%3A%5Cn%5Cn++++%2A+Redistributions+of+source+code+must+retain+the+above+copyright%5Cn++++++notice%2C+this+list+of+conditions+and+the+following+disclaimer.%5Cn++++%2A+Redistributions+in+binary+form+must+reproduce+the+above%5Cn++++++copyright+notice%2C+this+list+of+conditions+and+the+following%5Cn++++++disclaimer+in+the+documentation+and%2For+other+materials+provided%5Cn++++++with+the+distribution.%5Cn++++%2A+Neither+the+name+of+Google+Inc.+nor+the+names+of+its%5Cn++++++contributors+may+be+used+to+endorse+or+promote+products+derived%5Cn++++++from+this+software+without+specific+prior+written+permission.%5Cn%5CnTHIS+SOFTWARE+IS+PROVIDED+BY+THE+COPYRIGHT+HOLDERS+AND+CONTRIBUTORS+%5C%22AS+IS%5C%22+AND%5CnANY+EXPRESS+OR+IMPLIED+WARRANTIES%2C+INCLUDING%2C+BUT+NOT+LIMITED+TO%2C+THE+IMPLIED%5CnWARRANTIES+OF+MERCHANTABILITY+AND+FITNESS+FOR+A+PARTICULAR+PURPOSE+ARE%5CnDISCLAIMED.+IN+NO+EVENT+SHALL+THE+COPYRIGHT+OWNER+OR+CONTRIBUTORS+BE+LIABLE+FOR%5CnANY+DIRECT%2C+INDIRECT%2C+INCIDENTAL%2C+SPECIAL%2C+EXEMPLARY%2C+OR+CONSEQUENTIAL+DAMAGES%5Cn%28INCLUDING%2C+BUT+NOT+LIMITED+TO%2C+PROCUREMENT+OF+SUBSTITUTE+GOODS+OR+SERVICES%3B%5CnLOSS+OF+USE%2C+DATA%2C+OR+PROFITS%3B+OR+BUSINESS+INTERRUPTION%29+HOWEVER+CAUSED+AND+ON%5CnANY+THEORY+OF+LIABILITY%2C+WHETHER+IN+CONTRACT%2C+STRICT+LIABILITY%2C+OR+TORT%5Cn%28INCLUDING+NEGLIGENCE+OR+OTHERWISE%29+ARISING+IN+ANY+WAY+OUT+OF+THE+USE+OF+THIS%5CnSOFTWARE%2C+EVEN+IF+ADVISED+OF+THE+POSSIBILITY+OF+SUCH+DAMAGE.%5Cn%22%0A++%7D%2C%0A++%22authors%22%3A+%7B%0A++++%22Flutter+Dev+Team%22%3A+%22flutter-dev%40googlegroups.com%22%0A++%7D%2C%0A++%22source%22%3A+%7B%0A++++%22http%22%3A+%22https%3A%2F%2Fstorage.googleapis.com%2Fflutter_infra_release%2Fflutter%2Fd1b9a6938ad77326ac3a94d92bbc77933ed829ed%2Fdarwin-x64-release%2FFlutterMacOS.framework.zip%22%0A++%7D%2C%0A++%22documentation_url%22%3A+%22https%3A%2F%2Fflutter.dev%2Fdocs%22%2C%0A++%22pl%27&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
Searching for inspections failed: undefined method `map' for nil
Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro Max.
when I add shared_preferences package I get this error message
